# Is there any method to call eventListener for more than one time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to call the eventlistener for all of the 4 progress bar but it is only working on the first one .I had clone the div with id=mycontainer by using for loop but the eventListener will only recognize the first progress bar in other its not working .Here is my code

```
</head>
  <body >
   <div id="headdiv">
       <div id="mycontainer" style="width: auto;float: left;margin-left: 2%;">
    <input
      id="threshold"
      placeholder="threshold value"
      type="text"
      name="thresholdd"
      style="width: 120px; margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 0%; padding: 10px;" />
    <input
      id="live"
      placeholder="live value"
      type="text"
      name="livee"
      style="width: 120px; margin-bottom: 20px;padding: 10px;"   />

    <div id="progress-container" class="progress-container">
      <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const progressBar = window.document.getElementById("progress-bar");
    const progressContainer = window.document.getElementById( "progress-container");
    const threshold = window.document.getElementById("threshold"); 
    let thresholdValue, value;
    threshold.addEventListener("change", e => { thresholdValue = e.target.value;});
    live.addEventListener("change", e => {
      value = e.target.value;
      let percentValue = Math.floor((value / (2 * thresholdValue)) * 100);
      let percentMargin = Math.floor((25 * value) / 100);
      console.log(percentValue, percentMargin);
      if ( value < 100) {
        progressBar.style.height = `calc(${value}% - ${percentMargin}px)`;
      } else if (value => 100) {
        progressBar.style.height = `calc(100% - 25px)`;
      } else {
        progressBar.style.height = `0px`;
      }
      if (percentValue < 50) {
        progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        progressContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
      } else {
        progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        progressContainer.style.borderColor = "green";
      }
    });  
          for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
          {
 var headdiv=document.getElementById('headdiv');
var elem = document.querySelector('#mycontainer');
var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = 'mycontainer'+i;
headdiv.appendChild(clone);
}
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `id` to class

id should be unique to each element.

When you do `document.getElementById` it will return only first matched element.

So you have to use `class` instead of `id`.

As `document.getElementsByClassName` returns all matching elements with className.

Also you have to bind eventlistener on `document` and then check for element.

As your elements are dynamically created, and `addEventListener` only binds event on elements those are present in DOM.

Like

```js
const progressBar = window.document.getElementById("progress-bar");
const progressContainer = window.document.getElementById("progress-container");
const threshold = window.document.getElementsByClassName("threshold");
let thresholdValue, value;
const live = document.getElementsByClassName("live");

document.addEventListener("change", e => {
  if (e.target.className.indexOf('threshold') > -1) {
    thresholdValue = e.target.value;
  } else if (e.target.className.indexOf('live') > -1) {
    value = e.target.value;
    let percentValue = Math.floor((value / (2 * thresholdValue)) * 100);
    let percentMargin = Math.floor((25 * value) / 100);
    console.log(percentValue, percentMargin);
    if (value < 100) {
      progressBar.style.height = `calc(${value}% - ${percentMargin}px)`;
    } else if (value => 100) {
      progressBar.style.height = `calc(100% - 25px)`;
    } else {
      progressBar.style.height = `0px`;
    }
    if (percentValue < 50) {
      progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      progressContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
    } else {
      progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      progressContainer.style.borderColor = "green";
    }
  }
});
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var headdiv = document.getElementById('headdiv');
  var elem = document.querySelector('#mycontainer');
  var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = 'mycontainer' + i;
  headdiv.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="headdiv">
  <div id="mycontainer" style="width: auto;float: left;margin-left: 2%;">
    <input class="threshold" placeholder="threshold value" type="text" name="thresholdd" style="width: 120px; margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 0%; padding: 10px;" />
    <input class="live" placeholder="live value" type="text" name="livee" style="width: 120px; margin-bottom: 20px;padding: 10px;" />

    <div id="progress-container" class="progress-container">
      <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added working snippet. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection` so you have to loop through these elements. But In your case there is only one matched element present in DOM when we are binding eventlistener, so even loop won't work. You have bind `change` listener on `document`

Comment: I am sure this is not all working snippet which you wanted, but you will get an idea, what you have to do

Comment: yeah thanks .. all the input boxes showing result for the first progress bar only i'll sort out this

Comment: In case you lost feel free to ask. We are glad to help

Comment: i had tried by changing the id to className of the progress bar and progress container but its showing an error of : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: Here is a fiddle. With all the changes you have to do https://jsfiddle.net/368spt97/1/

Comment: Hey @Kenny ! can you help me out in solving the question problem on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921035/is-there-any-method-to-pass-multiple-selected-option-value-to-mongodb-using-reac?noredirect

Answer (score 1):

Give all the progress bars the same class:

```
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

Assign a variable to `document.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar")` - this will select all of them and return a Node list:

```
const bars = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar");
```

Loop through each one using `.forEach` and add an event listener to it:

```
bars.forEach(bar => bar.addEventListener("change", functionToRun);
```

Result: each progress bar has a "change" event listener assigned to it.

Comment: its not showing any result in the progress bars also not showing any error